# Accessing imageurl using userdefaults in objective c

Tags: objective-c, web-services, imageview, nsuserdefaults

I have fetched the image from image picker and uploaded the image to web service and i have a image url.I have saved the imageurl using user defaults as given below:

```
-(void)postSignupService {

[NewJsonHelperClass postExecuteWithParams:@"signup" secondParm:[self signUpParams] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){

    if ([[json valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"]) {

        NSDictionary *dataDict =[NSDictionary new];
        dataDict =[json valueForKey:@"user"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"sucess" forKey:@"LoginStatus"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dataDict valueForKey:@"_id"] forKey:@"user_Id"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dataDict valueForKey:@"userName"] forKey:@"userName"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dataDict valueForKey:@"password"] forKey:@"Password"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dataDict valueForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"email_Id"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dataDict valueForKey:@"profile_pic"] forKey:@"image_Str"];

        NSLog(@"datadict is %@",dataDict);

        SelectFoodVC *selectVc = [appDelegateRef.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectFoodVC"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectVc animated:YES];

    //    TabBarController *tabVc = [appDelegateRef.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
     //   [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabVc animated:YES];

    }

    else{
        [reUse showAlertWithTitle:[json valueForKey:@"status"] message:[json valueForKey:@"user"] thirdParam:self];
    }

}];

}
-(NSDictionary *)signUpParams {

    NSMutableDictionary *params =[NSMutableDictionary new];
    params[@"userName"] =self.userNameTf.text;
    params[@"email"] =self.emailTf.text;
    params[@"password"] =self.passwordTf.text;
    NSLog(@"imgstr is %@",imgStr);
    params[@"profile_pic"] =imgStr;


return params;
}
```

Here profile pic value is imgStr which is got as imageurl from web service.

When i try to retrieve the imageurl in different viewcontroller,the value of userdefault is null as it shows error.

```
NSString *urlstring = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image_Str"];
NSLog(@"urlstring is %@",urlstring);
```

Here urlstring is null and the error is Error: Request failed: not found (404)

Comment: try to print [dataDict valueForKey:@"profile_pic"] before you save it to verify it's value

Comment: If the Time between saving and loading is short you may consider using synchronize to Force immidiate saving of the userdefaults. otherwise the saving is handled by the OS.

Comment: I tried to synchronize,the null is solved,but the value always remains the same i mean old value,when i change the user also,the image url alone doesnt change.Any idea what is the issue?Above is the code i am using

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/1.jpeg"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setURL:url forKey:@"URL"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


   NSString *getURL = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]URLForKey:@"URL"];

    NSLog(@"url is %@",getURL);
```

Comment: i tried to synchronize,but the value of imageurl remains the same even if the  user id changes,the imageurl should change as per the profile.Is it because i added [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]; at the end ,thats y it is taking only that imageurl?